# Template template and partial specialization: a puzzle

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, partial-specialization

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename>
struct S { };

template<typename, typename>
struct B;

template <typename R, typename... Args, template<class> class C>
struct B<R(Args...), C<R>> {
    void f() { }
};

int main() {
    B<void(), S<void>> b;
    b.f();
}
```

It compiles and has no problem.
Anyway, whenever one decides to use `B`, it has to provide two types.
What I'd like to achieve is to default somehow the second parameter (I know, partial specializations do not accept a default for their parameters) and let an user define it's type as `B<void()>` instead of `B<void(), S<void>>`.
Unfortunately, because of template template, partial specialization and the dependency existent between the parameters, all together they lead to a puzzle against which I'm struggling since a couple of hours.

Is there any clever solution to do that?
So far, I have been able to solve it with intermediate structures, but I don't like it so much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial specializations don't accept default parameters, but the primary does. You can just add it there:

```
template<typename Sig, typename X = S<return_type_t<Sig>>>
struct B;
```

Then all you need to do is implement a return type metafunction for a signature. Something like:

```
template <class Sig>
struct return_type;

template <class Sig>
using return_type_t = typename return_type<Sig>::type;

template <class R, class... Args>
struct return_type<R(Args...)> {
    using type = R;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You may create an helper class for that:

```
template <typename T> struct default_arg;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct default_arg<R(Args...)>
{
    using type = S<R>;
};

template<typename Sign, typename T = typename default_arg<Sign>::type>
struct B;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5bb97508e511ff1)

Answer (score 1):

Here we change `B` into a template alias.

`B_t` does the default arg work.

`B_impl` is the implementation of `B` without any default args.

`B` is a `using` alias that gets the result of `B_t`.

```
template<class> struct S {};

template<class, class>
struct B_impl;

template<class R, class... Args, template<class...> class C>
struct B_impl<R(Args...), C<R>> {
  void f() { }
};

template<class, class=void>
struct B_t;

template<class R, class...Args>
struct B_t<R(Args...), void>:
  B_t<R(Args...),S<R>>
{};

template<class R, class... Args, template<class...> class C>
struct B_t<R(Args...), C<R>> {
  using type=B_impl<R(Args...), C<R>>;
};

template<class Sig, class Z=void>
using B=typename B_t<Sig,Z>::type;
```

The downside is that pattern-matching on `B` won't work well.